# Liferay importing millions of data using Service API

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder, liferay-6.2

I have a legacy table with about 1.7 million records in it. I am using Liferay's service builder api to insert these records in Liferay's table as per suggestion everywhere to use Liferay's service api for dealing with Liferay's tables.

Initially I used (Entity)LocalServiceUtil.getEntities(-1,-1) to fetch all the records and insert one by one, which I realized is a folly to read 1.7 million records in one go.

I then read the records from database in deltas of 5000. Although this is working, it is taking its own sweet time. Is there any other way to have this process faster? Or does a different value of delta would solve the problem?

Comment: Are you using the ServiceBuilder to access your legacy table? As you are saying: _use Liferay's service api for dealing with **Liferay's** tables_

Comment: Yes. I am using service builder for both source and destination.

Comment: And the destination table is a Liferay table?

Comment: Yes. I am able to pull the data from external datasource using configuration in ext-spring.xml and pushing the data into Liferay using the default data source.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you should use the API to access the database of Liferay.

But it is important to know why you should do this:

- Because the database layout is not documented and may change without notice between minor versions.
- Because you could overlook an implicit constraint which leads to spurious errors.
- Because changing the database of a running Liferay portal may lead to wrong cache entries.

But if none of these apply because

- you are filling the tables of *your* entities (where you know the exact layout) and
- you stopped your running Liferay portal

then you can use the functions of your database for bulk operations instead of using your service.